# How to copy a row from one mysql table to another

Tags: mysql, copy, row

Please forgive if already answered. I have looked at lots of other questions and none are helping! Basically, I want to copy a single row from one table, to another table. The problem I have struck, is the the id of the row I want to copy, is already in use, in the table I want to copy to. This is what I have at present, it works, until it strikes this problem.

```
 INSERT INTO venues SELECT * FROM submitted_venues WHERE id='9';
```

It generates the error: Duplicate entry '9' for key 'id'

Is there a way to change the id number on the fly, so that it create an unused new number for the receiving table, or do I have to write a query that names and gets all of the fields for each table. Some thing like the replace statement 0 cases would be good, where 0 creates a new record!!

The 9, is just a number that I used for this example, of course it changes.

---

EDIT:

I have created a work around for this problem.

```
//get highest id number of table to copy to
$sql = "SELECT id FROM venues ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if( $result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $to_id = $row[ 0 ];
    //increase id 
    $to_id ++;

    //get highest id number of table to copy from
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM submitted_venues ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    if( $result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) ){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $from_id = $row[ 0 ];
        //increase id 
        $from_id ++;

        //get highest unused id number
        $temp_id = $to_id > $from_id ? $to_id : $from_id;

        //update existing record to ensure that its id number will not conflict
        $sql = "UPDATE submitted_venues SET id = '$temp_id' WHERE id='$current_venue_id'";
        if( $result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) ){
            $current_venue_id = $temp_id;

            //copy record to normal regular venues table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO venues SELECT * FROM submitted_venues WHERE id='$current_venue_id'";
            if( ! $result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) )
                die("Could not copy -> " . mysqli_error($mysqli) );

            //delete record from temp db table
            $sql = "DELETE FROM submitted_venues WHERE id='$current_venue_id'";
            if( ! $result = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) )
                die("Could not delete -> " . mysqli_error($mysqli) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at ‘ON DUPLICATE KEY’ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: There is no syntax that allows you to exclude one column from the asterix wilcard. You can add calclulated columns, but in your case you will have to enumerate all, except id, which will be generated I suppose.

Comment: The table has 32 fields, so trying to avoid large queries. Can I increase the id number of that row, from the table I am copying from. I intend to delete this after the row is copied, so should not hurt anything. If so, all I need to do, is get the highest id from the table I am copying to, then add 1!